# Django 1.7 Data Type Binding Oracle

Tags: python, django, oracle, type-conversion, cx-oracle

I've recently upgraded from Django1.4 to Django1.7 with an Oracle backend and have noticed that the following query is extremely slow:

```
DomainObject.objects.get(some_colume=some_value)
```

while this on is very quick:

```
DomainObject.objects.filter(some_colume=some_value)[0]
```

I've profiled both in Oracle Enterprise manager and the difference is that the bind variable for the first query is being passed by the driver as a NVARCHAR2 while the second is being passed as a VARCHAR2.
Since the column is a VARCHAR2 the second query can use the index that's been defined on the column, while the first one can't.

Any ideas on why Django is passing the first query as an NVARCHAR2 and the second as a VARCHAR2?

Thanks,
Vackar

Comment: I've also noticed that Django adds what appears to be completly useless paging info to the 'get' query. Workaround is to run:
from django.db.models import query
query.MAX_GET_RESULTS=1

Comment: I assume you mean 'from Django 1.4 to Django 1.7'

Comment: Apologies, yes you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

So the only way that I've managed to get around this is, is to monkey patch the Django param generator function as follows:

**monkey_patch_query.py**

```
from django.db.backends.oracle.base import FormatStylePlaceholderCursor

def _stringify(val):
    if isinstance(val, unicode):
        return str(val)
    else:
        return val

def proper_param_generator(self, params):
    # Try dict handling; if that fails, treat as sequence
    if hasattr(params, 'items'):
        return dict((k, _stringify(v.force_bytes)) for k, v in params.items())
    else:
        return [_stringify(p.force_bytes) for p in params]

FormatStylePlaceholderCursor._param_generator = proper_param_generator
```

**Settings.py**

```
from monkey_patch_query import *
```

May be useful for someone else who also encounters this issue.